# ERROR 1136 (21S01) when INSERT data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

A MySQL table called SQ was created as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE SQ(
SQno INT PRIMARY KEY,
Question VARCHAR(100)
);
```

After I was trying to enter data to that table like this,

```
INSERT INTO SQ (SQno, Question) VALUES(
    (1,'What primary school did you attend?'),
    (2,'In what town or city did your parents meet?'),
    (3,'In what city or town was your first job?'),
);
```

But there was an error occurs, and shows as this,

**`ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`**

So, please help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get rid of the outer set of parentheses; each row should have parentheses around it but not also all the rows:

```
INSERT INTO SQ (SQno, Question) VALUES
    (1,'What primary school did you attend?'),
    (2,'In what town or city did your parents meet?'),
    (3,'In what city or town was your first job?')
;
```